# Python Server and Java Client: Weird behaviour receiving data

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I am using python to create a server, and Java(Android) to create a client. The problem I am facing is getting the data correctly from one to the other.

I let the Java client attempt a login like this:

```
SettingsManager settingsman = SettingsManager.getInstance(params[0]);
                int port = Integer.parseInt(settingsman.getPort());
                String ip = settingsman.getIp();
                server = new Socket(ip, port);
                input = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                output = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                output.writeChars(LOGIN_REQ);
                output.writeChars(settingsman.getUserName());
                output.writeChars(settingsman.getPassword());
                String token = Integer.toString(input.read());
                //Check if the login has failed
                if(token == "0"){
                    token = null;
                }
                return token;
```

And the Python server receives it like this:

```
    opcode = c.recv(2)
    opcode  = opcode.decode('utf-8')
    print("OPCODE:" + opcode + str(type(opcode)))
    if(opcode == "0"):
        "Login action"
        print("STARTING TO RECV!")
        login = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("RECEIVED LOGIN: " + login)
        password = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("PASSWORD: " + password)
        print("USERNAME: " + username)
        setman = SettingsManager()
        setuser = setman.seccam_user()
        setpass = setman.seccam_password()

        if login == setuser & password == setpass:
            print("Login is good!")
            """Generate random token and save it to the settings file"""
    elif(opcode == "1"):
        pass
    else:
        print("OTHER!")
```

This is the output:

```
OPCODE:0<class 'str'>
OTHER!
```

Even though the Opcode seems to be a string and is the right value, the program doesn't enter the If statement correctly

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed my issue. Using WriteBytes in my Java code is working better!